# sizeWithFont does not get marked as deprecated when working with array, it is safe then?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode6, deprecated

If I write it as follows no deprecation alert shows up:

```
NSArray *aboutInfo=[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"blah"];
CGSize textSize = [[aboutInfo objectAtIndex:0] sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize: 14.0] constrainedToSize:wSz2xh lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping ];
```

However this is marked as deprecated:

```
NSString *aboutInfo=@"blah";
CGSize textSize = [aboutInfo sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize: 14.0] constrainedToSize:wSz2xh lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping ];
```

Both work fine.

Would that mean that 1st code is safe?

I use XCode 6.2, app's project and targets deployment target is iOS7.1

Comment: If you know it's deprecated, why are you still using it? Update to the newer method in both cases.

Comment: good point rmaddy, just was curious. it is old app i am updating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would assume XCode doesn't mark the first one as deprecated because it can't be sure the first receiver really is an `NSString`. The method you are talking about is deprecated nonetheless.